# Correct P values from Chi-squared test by sample size

Tags: chi-squared-test

I am working with results from a chi-squared test of homogeneity, but I'm struggling with the idea behind this test, since the chi-squared statistic can only increase with the number of observations, and then some P values are returned that are more significant that others probably just because of a higher number of observations. Lets put an example:

```
Nobs <- c(34, 34, 41, 28)
Nexp <- c(26, 44, 45, 22)
```

The chi-square statistic here is 6.73 (P = 0.08, df = 3), calculated as:

```
((Nobs - Nexp)^2 / Nexp) %>% sum()
```

However, if I consider now a second set of data less biased from the null expectation (e.g. with Nobs/Nexp -1 closer to zero overall), with the same number of categories, but with much higher number of observations for each one of these, the value of chi-squared increases, just because I am relying on more data, eg:

```
Nobs2 <- c(180, 422, 341, 211)
Nexp2 <- c(212, 372, 348, 222)
```

Which gives chi-squared = 12.24 (P = 6.6e-3).

Is there a way to correct these P values by the underlying number of observations, so these are comparable?

Thank you

Comment: "The chi-squared statistic can only increase with the number of observations", this is the principle of statistical power: differences (even small) in large sample sizes are less likely due to sampling fluctuations than in small sample sizes, hence you get smaller p-values. Why would you want to correct the p-value?

Comment: I feel that otherwise the comparison between the two P values is not fair. Or at least that differences in these P values are is not only a reflection of the differences between the two samples (their composition), but also of the differences in sample size for one and another. Ideally, a correction would allow to make a comparison between two different P values in a way that it is independent of sample size.

Comment: You should beware of comparing p-values in the first place. They are NOT a measure of effect size, for example. If you understand what a p-value is, it's *obvious* that they must take sample size into account in the way that they do.

Comment: An example. If I toss a coin twice and get heads twice, is that a strong indication I have a biased coin? (No, getting the same side twice happens half the time with a fair coin; it's a completely unremarkable outcome) .... But if I toss a coin 200 times and get 200 heads is that a strong indication I have a biased coin? Absolutely!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effect you are observing --- that the *p* value decreases with a larger sample size for the same effect size --- is a feature of *p* values. That's just the way *p* values work.

In contrast, a proper effect size statistic will not increase as the sample size increases for the same effect size.  It's a good practice to report effect size statistics, or some other measure of effect size (like proportions or differences in means).

For a chi-square test of association, common effect size statistics are *phi* and Cramer's *V*

For a chi-square goodness-of-fit test, there's no standard effect size statistic that I know of, except maybe just comparing observed proportions to theoretical proportions.

But also for a goodness-of-fit test we can make a modification of Cramer *V* statistic, taking the square root of the chi-square value divided by the sample size divided by the number of categories minus 1.  See details at the documentation for [this function in the `rcompanion` package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rcompanion/versions/2.3.21/topics/cramerVFit), with the caveat that I am the author of this package, and the code below.

To demonstrate how effect sizes are independent of sample size, I'm going to create a third set of values which has the same proportions as `Nobs` and `Nexp`, but with three times the sample size.

You'll note the proportions and modified Cramer's *V* statistic are the same for `Nobs` and for `Nobs3`.

```
Nobs = c(34, 34, 41, 28)
Nexp = c(26, 44, 45, 22)
Pexp = Nexp / sum(Nexp)

chisq.test(Nobs, p = Pexp)

   ### Chi-squared test for given probabilities
   ###
   ### X-squared = 6.7262, df = 3, p-value = 0.08116

### Report proportions observed

Pnobs = Nobs / sum(Nobs)

Pnobs

   ### 0.2481752 0.2481752 0.2992701 0.2043796

Pexp

   ### 0.1897810 0.3211679 0.3284672 0.1605839

### Modified Cramer's V

Chi.sq    = chisq.test(x=Nobs, p=Pexp)$statistic
K         = length(Nobs)
N         = sum(Nobs)
CV        = sqrt(Chi.sq/N/(K-1))
names(CV) = "Modified Cramer's V"
CV

   ### Modified Cramer's V 
   ###           0.1279274  

# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # 

Nobs3 = Nobs * 3
Nexp3 = Nexp * 3
Pexp3 = Nexp3 / sum(Nexp3)

chisq.test(Nobs3, p = Pexp3)

   ### Chi-squared test for given probabilities
   ###
   ### X-squared = 20.179, df = 3, p-value = 0.0001559

### Report proportions observed

Pnobs3 = Nobs3 / sum(Nobs3)

Pnobs3

   ### 0.2481752 0.2481752 0.2992701 0.2043796

Pexp3

   ### 0.1897810 0.3211679 0.3284672 0.1605839

### Modified Cramer's V

Chi.sq    = chisq.test(x=Nobs3, p=Pexp3)$statistic
K         = length(Nobs3)
N         = sum(Nobs3)
CV        = sqrt(Chi.sq/N/(K-1))
names(CV) = "Modified Cramer's V"
CV

   ### Modified Cramer's V 
   ###           0.1279274
```